# How to add item to cart programmatically in client side? e-shop WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I will buy product at e-shop that built with e-shop Word Press.
i'd like to programmatically process of buy.
i know the code javascript for  every parts of process cart.
except *payment tab* i will fill it manual.

for example:
1:it's add product to cart and go to there`addToBasketFunc(68);`
2:it's change count to 2.

```
$("select[name=ori_0]").val(2);
$("select[name=ori_0]").trigger('change');
```

and so on ...
i will do it because The number of products is low and there are many applicants.

**Question**:
How to run `script` after period of time for load every tab?
Is there a tool for this?

Comment: Have you considered to make a browser addon? I have problems to completely understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want use software/extention that can speed up add item to cart.

Comment: I think I'd like software same ```BotChief``` but that's free.